# Image upload not saving file in Django

Tags: python, django

No errors when hitting upload. But the image doesn't appear where I have indicated it ought to. Put an absolute path in MEDIA_ROOT and referenced the same in (upload_to) param ImageField. Not sure what I am missing.

Model:

```
class FileUploadHandler(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/bin/mideastinfo/wiki/static/')
```

View:

```
from models import Article, Edit
from forms import ArticleForm, EditForm
from forms import *
from PIL import Image
from models import FileUploadHandler

def image_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            FileUploadHandler(request.FILES['image'])
            return render_to_response('wiki/gallery.html')
    else:
        form = UploadImageForm()
    return render_to_response('wiki/gallery.html', RequestContext(request, {'form': form}))
```

Forms.py:

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = FileUploadHandler
    #image = forms.ImageField()\
    fields = ['title']
```

Comment: Is the user running Django allowed to write to /Python27/Lib/ ?

Comment: That's a good question. I am the user and am basically working in this path as my development environment

Comment: Someone else suggested I use a relative path as opposed to the absolute one, but I read elsewhere the contrary. Any best practices out there?

Answer (score 0):

Here you didn't save it in views. Just use this:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        newfile = FileUploadHandler(title='anything', file=request.FILES['image'])
        newfile.save()
```

Comment: This didn't work. Earlier I tried to add form.save to my existing code and I get an attributeError. The data is bound to the form, right? So why not form.save?

Comment: Actually if you use `forms.Form`(in forms.py) you will get this error. If you use `forms.ModelForm` instead, `form.save` will work.

Comment: In the model? I am using models.Model.

Comment: I meant about this class `UploadImageForm()` in forms.py

Comment: hmm, made the change. No error, but no saving either. Going to add forms.py to above

Answer (score 0):

I think you're working a little too hard. You shouldn't have to call the FileUploadHandler model directly to save the image.

First, your form should be:

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FileUploadHandler
```

And your view should be:

```
from forms import UploadImageForm

def image_upload(request):
    form = UploadImageForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return render_to_response('wiki/gallery.html', RequestContext(request, {'form': form}))
```

Since you're using a ModelForm, you just need to save the form once it's been validated. Just make sure that the file field is visible in your template. You were excluding the 'file' field in your form earlier that's why it wasn't working.

Update: Simplified your view even more just because...

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be the template:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Notice: **`enctype="multipart/form-data"`**